# Getting ExecuteError: ERROR 001558: Error parsing JSON file in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, json, arcgis-10.7, error-001558

I'm trying to convert some open-source data in JSON format to a shapefile for use in ArcGIS Desktop.  I'm attempting to do this in ArcPy with ArcMap 10.7.  The data I'm trying to access is here, in JSON format:

[data from data.SF.gov](https://data.sfgov.org/resource/ygmz-vaxd.json)

And my script:

```
#access the JSON from web link
bikeLanesRaw = 'https://data.sfgov.org/resource/ygmz-vaxd.json'
bikeLanesRawResponse = urllib2.urlopen(bikeLanesRaw)
bikeLanesRaw_JSON = bikeLanesRawResponse.read()
#Write each response to JSON
foo = open(bikeFacilitiesFolder + "\\" + "bikeLanes_SF.json", "wb")
foo.write(bikeLanesRaw_JSON);
foo.close()



#Convert JSON to shapefile - THIS FAILS
arcpy.JSONToFeatures_conversion(bikeFacilitiesFolder + "\\" + "bikeLanes_SF.json", bikeFacilitiesFolder + "\\" + "bikeLanes_SF.shp")
```

Everything works as expected until the final line, where I try and convert the JSON to features.  It gives me the error:

```
 ExecuteError: ERROR 001558: Error parsing json file 'Bike Facilities Data\bikeLanes_SF.json'. 
Failed to execute (JSONToFeatures).
```

I've read more of ESRI documentation, and they say:

*Review the JSON structure in the input file. The JSON must have at least the geometryType, spatialReference, fields, and features (with geometry and attributes) property.*

What do I do if the JSON does not have this information to begin with?

Comment: Rather than provide only a link to a (presumably large) JSON file when potential answerers may be like me and prefer not to follow links, I think you should cut that JSON file down to a tiny sample that can be posted here as text, but still be used to show the error.

Answer (score 4):

The JSON to Features tool won't work for your case.

The tool wants either **esri** JSON or **geoJSON**. The JSON from that link is neither of those, it's straight up regular JSON. You'll need to find another parser to turn JSON into a shape/fgdb/geo-something.

You could research using cursors and building your own featureclass by parsing the JSON manually. There should be a lot of starter code on GIS.SE and the internet at large.

Comment: From what it sounds like, it should work with a GeoJSON.  I'm able to find a Geojson of the data:   https://data.sfgov.org/resource/ygmz-vaxd.geojson , though it's still giving me the same error when I pass this into JSON to Features tool?

Comment: Which product are you using? The ability to convert from GeoJSON was introduced at Pro 2.2 and appears to have never been back ported to ArcMap.

Comment: I'm using ArcMap 10.7 .  What about using arcPy's "AsShape"?  This supposedly converts geojson to ESRI JSON, though I haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: You might be able to use that. I'd try that. If you can't get it to work, that'd be a new question here.